# Show all available Google accounts on login screen

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, login, android-app

Currently on the login screen only one account is shown below “Log in using Google” even if there are multiple Google accounts on the phone. While clicking on “Log in using Google” does bring up a list of available accounts this wasn't immediately obvious to me and I assumed that I'd be logged in on the account listed, I only discovered a list appeared when installing the application on a second device.

I think that if there is more than one account available then either showing all of the accounts available or none of the accounts would be more intuitive for a user. Perhaps if the phone only has one account then stick with displaying that account name?

Edit: Sorry about a lack of screenshot (and hand drawn circle..) the device I have available at the moment has a broken power button so I can't take one, perhaps someone could edit one in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed a while ago, the app now only shows your e-mail address below the button if you only have one Google account on your device.

Answer (score 0):

Ideal solution can be either:

```
If one account is added then
  display that account under Log in using Google title
else if more accounts are added then
  don't display anything, clicking on button it should show list of added accounts
```